# two legends based on different datasets with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to have two legends with ggplot2 but based on different datasets ? For instance, in the code below I would like to get both the legend of the first situation and the legend of the second situation in the same graphic. My attempt (third situation) does not work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

yrng <- range(economics$unemploy)
xrng <- range(economics$date)
presidential <- presidential[-(1:3), ]

# add a fictive factor to the economics dataset
economics <- cbind.data.frame(economics, col=gl(2, nrow(economics)/2))

#####################
## first situation ##
#####################
# first plot with legend
unemp <- qplot(date, unemploy, data=economics, geom="line",
                 xlab = "", ylab = "No. unemployed (1000s)", colour=col)
# second plot without legend
unemp + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = start), data = presidential)

######################
## second situation ##
######################
# first plot without legend
unemp <- qplot(date, unemploy, data=economics, geom="line",
                 xlab = "", ylab = "No. unemployed (1000s)")
# second plot with legend
unemp + 
  geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = start, xmax = end,
                    fill = party), ymin = yrng[1], ymax = yrng[2],
                    data = presidential) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), 0.2))


#####################
## third situation ##
#####################
# first plot with legend
unemp <- qplot(date, unemploy, data=economics, geom="line",
                 xlab = "", ylab = "No. unemployed (1000s)", colour=col)
# second plot with legend
unemp + 
  geom_rect(aes(NULL, NULL, xmin = start, xmax = end, fill = party), ymin = yrng[1],
              ymax = yrng[2], data = presidential) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), 0.2))

Error in data.frame(xmin = 11342, xmax = 14264, fill = "Republican", colour = function   (x,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Comment: Your code should ideally be easy to cut and paste into R. As is you currently have `>` and `+` characters that don't makes this possible. Hard to see what you are doing as a result.

Comment: @mindless.panda This is not a problem: copy the code and then do "Paste commands only" in the R console :-)

Comment: You are assuming everyone uses the standard R console. =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, once I start getting to more complicated plots, its almost always better to stop using `qplot` and use `ggplot` instead. I find it easier to think about how I'm building the plot up piece by piece:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=unemploy, color=col), data=economics) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, fill=party),
            ymin = yrng[1], ymax = yrng[2], data = presidential) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("blue", "red"), 0.2)) +           
  xlab("") +
  ylab("No. unemployed (1000s)")
```

This gives:

[image: plot]