# Adding multiple legends to ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have following multi-layered plot:

```
df <- data.frame(number = 1:10, 
                 values = rnorm(10), 
                 decision = factor(rbinom(10,1,.5), levels = c(0,1),
                                   labels=c("No","Yes")),
                 expValues = rnorm(10),
                 bandwidth = runif(10, 0,1))

ggplot(df,aes(x = number, y = values, color=decision)) + aes(group=NA) +
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  geom_point(size = 3,shape = 16) + 
  geom_smooth(data = df, aes(ymin = values-bandwidth , ymax = values+bandwidth), 
              stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(data=df,
             aes(x=number,y=expValues),shape = "x", size = 5, color = "blue") +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(x = Inf, y = max(df$values), label = "Mean  = 12"), 
            aes(label=label, x =  x, y = y) ,
            hjust = 1, vjust = -0.1, color = "brown", size = 10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=mean(df$values) ,color="blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

I want to add legends for `geom_hline` and `geom_point` with shape "x", denoting the for the first it is "Cut Value", for the second "Expected Value".

How can I do that?

Note: I checked [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394391/r-custom-legend-for-multiple-layer-ggplot) post and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687739/two-legends-based-on-different-datasets-with-ggplot2) post for possible solutions but cannot figure out how can I do it for especially `geom_hline`.

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/guides.html

Comment: @N8TRO I understand from the page that one can add legends to different scales within main `data.frame` used in `ggplot()`. But it is not obvious from the page you linked how to do it for, for example `geom_hline()`. Can you kindly share your insights with a bit more detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add legends, the first thing to do is to actually map something to the desired aesthetic.  For example, right now you've set the point shape as `x`, but you didn't *map* it inside of `aes` so you don't get a legend.  You can map to constants as well as to variables to force a legend.

For your `geom_point` layer, you can just move `shape` inside `aes`, mapped to whatever constant you like.  Using some value that indicates what it is will make the legend editing easier.

```
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=number, y=expValues, shape = "Expected value"), size = 5, color = "blue")
```

For the `geom_hline`, you'll need a dataset specific to the layer for mapping purposes.  Depending on the route you go, you may also need to set `show_guide` to `TRUE` in this layer.

```
geom_hline(data = data.frame(yint = mean(df$values)), aes(...), show_guide = TRUE)
```

You could make two separate legends.  You could also combine the line and shapes into a single legend as in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529687/2461552).  Both options will involve setting values in the appropriate `scale_xxx_manual` and using `override.aes` in `guide_legend`.

Here is how you could make a single new legend.  Notice I had to add `geom_hline` before `geom_line` to make the `decision` legend look right.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = number, y = values, color=decision, group = NA)) +
    geom_hline(data = data.frame(yint = mean(df$values)),
        aes(yintercept = yint, shape = "Cut value"), 
             color="blue", linetype = 2, show_guide = TRUE) +
    geom_line(size = 1) + 
    geom_point(size = 3,shape = 16) + 
    geom_smooth(data = df, aes(ymin = values-bandwidth , ymax = values+bandwidth), 
              stat = "identity") +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=number, y=expValues, shape = "Expected value"), 
             size = 5, color = "blue") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(x = Inf, y = max(df$values), label = "Mean  = 12"), 
        aes(label=label, x =  x, y = y),
        hjust = 1, vjust = -0.1, color = "brown", size = 10) +      
    theme(text=element_text(size=20)) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "", values = c("x", "x")) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2, 0), 
                                            shape = c(NA, "x"))))
```

**Edit** Add a legend for the error band ribbon

I couldn't quite get things working with `fill` to add a third legend based on the error band ribbon.  You could do this as three separate legends, although I don't think the spacing is as nice:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = number, y = values, color=decision, group = NA)) +
    geom_hline(data = data.frame(yint = mean(df$values)),
        aes(yintercept = yint, linetype = "Cut value"), 
             color="blue", show_guide = TRUE) +
    geom_line(size = 1) + 
    geom_point(size = 3,shape = 16) + 
    geom_smooth(data = df, aes(ymin = values-bandwidth , ymax = values+bandwidth, fill = "Error band"), 
              stat = "identity") +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=number, y=expValues, shape = "Expected value"), 
             size = 5, color = "blue") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(x = Inf, y = max(df$values), label = "Mean  = 12"), 
        aes(label=label, x =  x, y = y),
        hjust = 1, vjust = -0.1, color = "brown", size = 10) +  
    theme(text=element_text(size=20)) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "", values = "x") +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = 2) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = "grey") +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
          fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
          color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

Alternatively, with some work inside `override.aes`, this could be done with the combination of `colour` and `size` along with `linetype` and `shape`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = number, y = values, color=decision, group = NA)) +
    geom_hline(data = data.frame(yint = mean(df$values)),
        aes(yintercept = yint, shape = "Cut value"), 
             color="blue", linetype = 2, show_guide = TRUE) +
    geom_line(size = 1) + 
    geom_point(size = 3,shape = 16) + 
    geom_smooth(data = df, aes(ymin = values-bandwidth , ymax = values+bandwidth, shape = "Error band"), 
              stat = "identity", show_guide = FALSE) +
    geom_point(data=df, aes(x=number, y=expValues, shape = "Expected value"), 
             size = 5, color = "blue") +
    geom_text(data = data.frame(x = Inf, y = max(df$values), label = "Mean  = 12"), 
        aes(label=label, x =  x, y = y),
        hjust = 1, vjust = -0.1, color = "brown", size = 10) +  
    theme(text=element_text(size=20)) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "", values = rep("x", 3)) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(2, 1, 0), 
                                           size = c(.5, 10, 5),
                                           shape = c(NA, NA, "x"),
                                           colour = c("blue", "grey75", "blue"))))
```

Comment: I thought I should write `linetype` within `aes` in `geom_hline`. Also for the last line, `override.aes`, I thought there should be three elements in the list, additional one for `decision`.  Very nice solution, thank you. By any chance, is there a possibility to write "Error Band" for the explanation for `geom_smooth`?

Comment: @HBat  I couldn't seem to quite get `fill` added correctly to a single shape legend (which is needed to show the Error Band). You can either be tricky in `override.aes` with the a `size`/`linetype`/`colour` combo or add three separate legends. I've edited to demonstrate.